# Is my code implementing a Factory pattern ? Is this a bad design?

Tags: design-patterns

I am new to software design patterns and trying factory design (creational pattern) to implement in my application for encryption/decryption using key.

I want to make sure this is Factory pattern and if its a bad design. Also if you can help how to improve it .

My code is follows :

abstract base class :

```
public abstract class EncryptDecrypt {
protected Key getKey() {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(getKeyValue().getBytes(), getAlgorithm());
    return key;
}
protected Cipher getCipher() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(getAlgorithm());
    return c;
}

protected abstract String getKeyValue();
protected abstract String getAlgorithm();

public final String encryptText(String valueToEnc) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    String keyValue = getKeyValue();
    String algorithm = getAlgorithm();
    Key key = getKey();
    Cipher c = getCipher();
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encValue));
    return encryptedValue;
}

public final String decryptText(String encryptedValue) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    String keyValue = getKeyValue();
    String algorithm = getAlgorithm();
    Key key = getKey();
    Cipher c = getCipher();
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedValue);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}
}
```

and following is a sample AES implementation :

```
public class AESEncryptDecrypt extends EncryptDecrypt {

@Override
protected String getKeyValue() {
    return "ThisIsA Key 1234";
}

@Override
protected String getAlgorithm() {
    return "AES";
}
}
```

Client class :

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    EncryptDecrypt ed = new AESEncryptDecrypt();
    String msg = "Text message@yahoo.com";
    String e = ed.encryptText(msg);
    System.out.println(e);
    System.out.println(ed.decryptText(e));
}

}
```

Thank you so much for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Your design looks to be more like Template design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A factory pattern [1] is a way to hide and simplify the Object creation. For instance, if you have many implementations of `EncryptDecrypt` algorithms and each of them with different initialization and configuration, then for a user will be difficult to use these implementations because there are too many and with different configurations and to use them the user will need to read lot of information to understand how to create the Object he needs. So, a Factory pattern helps providing a unique Interface where a user have all different implementations of `EncryptDecrypt` algorithms and methods to create them without needing to know how to initialize them.

Think that you are in a restaurant with tons of food and you want to order something. How do you think it would be if there were no menu? You would need to check all kind of food and preparations in order to figure out what do you want. Factory works like a menu where you have all the options together and organized for an easy use.

Now if you look the `EncryptDecrypt` usage

```
EncryptDecrypt ed = new AESEncryptDecrypt();
String msg = "Text message@yahoo.com";
String e = ed.encryptText(msg);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(ed.decryptText(e));
```

you will note that it is not creating any Object, it is not like the menu. In fact the `EncryptDecrypt` itself is the object that does all the work. But in the other hand you have

```
protected Key getKey() {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(getKeyValue().getBytes(), getAlgorithm());
    return key;
}
protected Cipher getCipher() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(getAlgorithm());
    return c;
}
```

and this is more like a Factory, where you are hiding the Object (Ciper and Key) creation to the user and he doesn't have to know even that those Objects exists.

So, my answers is that `EncryptDecrypt` is not a Factory and in order to do that you need to separate the Object creation (Factory) of the Object usage.

**references:**

[1] [Wikipedia, Factory pattern definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).